# New export action for pages in magnolia cms

Tags: magnolia

I need to create a new export action for the page app in magnolia cms that would always export selected page elements to a YAML file.
I would like to override the class definition and the dialog definition for the existing export action since I do not need a dialog that lets me select YAML or XML. It will always be YAML in my case.
I setup a new Maven module and created a new action for the Page app.
How do I configure a custom class for this action?  How do I get the current context of the page in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the dialog attached to the action first. If you plan to have a custom action then simply do not configure one. We already have two actions for those two cases. If you are interested in YAML export use the following: `info.magnolia.ui.framework.action.ExportYamlAction`

Comment: Thanks @Ducaz035. I configured two actions for exporting the YAML configuration of the node. The second one (exportYAML2) using ExportYamlActionDefinition does not show up in the actionbar for the page even though I added it as an item. Is there anything else I need to configure for it?
exportYaml with class info.magnolia.ui.framework.action.OpenExportDialogActionDefinition works.
exportYaml2 with class info.magnolia.ui.framework.action.ExportYamlActionDefinition doesn't work. Availability for it is set to info.magnolia.ui.framework.availability.IsNotDeletedRule.

Comment: @AnaSustic that is weird, can you please copy all your app configuration to somewhere here? :)

Comment: I did as another answer to my original question since I couldn't in the comment :)

Comment: I revisited your answer here @Ducaz035 and was wondering if there is anything ExportYAMLAction needs other then the class definition `info.magnolia.ui.framework.action.ExportYamlActionDefinition`. From what I see it should send a YAML file for the current object to the browser. Unfortunately I do not get it. There is no error in the catalina.out

Comment: Does your browser somehow block the request?

Comment: I am pretty sure the browser (Chrome) does not block the requests since it saves the YAML file correctly when I use the action class `info.magnolia.ui.framework.action.ExportActionDefinition`

Comment: @AnaSustic If we talking about stock exportAction, it also requires a command to be set and the default value is 'exportYaml'.

Comment: Hi @Ducaz035. 
We are talking about the /info/magnolia/ui/framework/action/ExportYamlAction.html. I called the action ExportYamlAction the class is info.magnolia.ui.framework.action.ExportYamlActionDefinition and the command is default-exportYaml. When I execute this action on a page nothing happens. I am expecting a temporary YAML file for the page in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

My action configuration for exportYAML2
[image: Action configuration]

My actionbar configuration for exportYAML
[image]

*** repeating the content of the comment below since I could not post pictures in the comment ***
I configured two actions for exporting the YAML configuration of the node.

The second one (exportYAML2) using ExportYamlActionDefinition does not show up in the actionbar for the page even though I added it as an item.

Is there anything else I need to configure for it?

`exportYaml` with class `info.magnolia.ui.framework.action.OpenExportDialogActionDefinition` works. `exportYaml2` with class `info.magnolia.ui.framework.action.ExportYamlActionDefinition` doesn't work. Availability for it is set to `info.magnolia.ui.framework.availability.IsNotDeletedRule`.

Comment: Can you show me how you define the exportYAML2 action under actions section?

Comment: So it is:
--pages>apps>pages>subApps>browser>actions>exportYAML2.
`exportYAML2` is a content node under actions.

Comment: you have to also define a class under the content node. It should be a type of actionDefinition. Have a look at: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Action+definition

Comment: I am sorry @Ducaz035 but I am not sure what are you referring to when you point "Define a class under the content node of type actionDefinition".

Comment: Nevermind, seen the first image now. That is indeed the correct way to configure that. Anything in your logs or in the Definitions App?

Comment: OK :) @Ducaz035 There is one error in the Definitions App for pages app `Failed to process collection entry due to [null] ` in location SubApps/browser/actionbar/sections/1/groups/3/items/0.

Comment: Can you attach the whole file here, please? :D I want to see it in a live instance.

Comment: I am afraid I am not allowed to send the logs due to privacy issues :(

Comment: :( I'd try to solve it with the information of the Definitions App then. Sorry, cannot help you further without knowing the app configuration.

Comment: This is solved. I did not have a proper configuration under actionbar. My fault :) Thanks so much for your help @Ducaz035 :)

Answer (score 0):

It is solved.

There are two things I needed to configure for a custom action in the pages app in magnolia.

configuration app modules>pages>apps>pages>subApps>browser>actions>MyAction withe class={custom or common class [from https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Action+definition](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Action+definition) }

modules>pages>apps>pages>subApps>browser>actionbar>sections>pageActions>groups>uniquegroupname>items-MyAction